# Exception thrown by IBM MQ .Net Native library when trying to get a message off the queue

Tags: .net, ibm-mq

Our client application uses the IBM .Net native library for interacting with our Websphere MQ server (V7.0.1).  I can't figure out the cause of the issue. If you have any helpful suggestions to help diagnose the issue, please let me know.

When trying to pull a message off a local queue the IBM library throws an exception which generated the following "FDC" file;

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                             |
| WebSphere MQ First Failure Symptom Report                                   |
| =========================================                                   |
|                                                                             |
| Date/Time         :- Mon October 17 2016 16:48:49 GMT Daylight Time         |
| UTC Time          :- 1476719329.480000                                      |
| UTC Time Offset   :- 60 (GMT Daylight Time)                                 |
| Host Name         :- ALXMQ001                                               |
| Operating System  :- Windows Ver 6.1 (3) Server Enterprise x64 Edition,     |
|   Build 7601: SP1                                                           |
| PIDS              :- 5724H7220                                              |
| LVLS              :- 7.0.1.0                                                |
| Product Long Name :- WebSphere MQ for Windows                               |
| Vendor            :- IBM                                                    |
| Probe Id          :- DN133001                                               |
| Application Name  :- MQM                                                    |
| Component         :- MQFAP.LeaveCall()                                      |
| SCCS Info         :- lib/dotnet/pc/winnt/nmqi/managed/MQFAP.cs, 1.7         |
| Line Number       :- 234                                                    |
| Build Date        :- Aug 13 2009                                            |
| CMVC level        :- p000-L090813                                           |
| Build Type        :- IKAP - (Production)                                    |
| UserID            :- ALXMQ001$                                              |
| Process Name      :- D:\OurCompany\OURAPP\STAGING_v1.1\Console\OURAPP.Windo   |
|                      wsService.exe                                          |
| Addressing mode   :- 32-bit                                                 |
| Process           :- 00005492                                               |
| Thread            :- 00000001                                               |
| UserApp           :- TRUE                                                   |
| Last HQC          :- 0.0.0-0                                                |
| Last HSHMEMB      :- 0.0.0-0                                                |
| Major Errorcode   :- MQRC_UNEXPECTED_ERROR                                  |
| Minor Errorcode   :- OK                                                     |
| Probe Type        :- INCORROUT                                              |
| Probe Severity    :- 4                                                      |
| Probe Description :- AMQ6125: An internal WebSphere MQ error has occurred.  |
| FDCSequenceNumber :- 0                                                      |
|                                                                             |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

MQM Function Stack
MQQueueManager.Disconnect()1
MQManagedObject.Close()
ManagedNmqiMQ.MQCLOSE(Hconn,Phobj,int,out int,out int)
MQFAP.LeaveCall()
xcsFFST

MQM Trace History
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxQueryProcAddr rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciSpxFreeMem rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciSpxFreeMem rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciLoadTransportExit rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciUdpCheckConfig rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciSpxAcceptConv rc=MQRC_NO_MSG_UNDER_CURSOR
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciSpxAllocConv rc=MQRC_NO_MSG_UNDER_CURSOR
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxSetConvClass rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxSetConvClass rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciSslSecureAllocConv rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciSslSecureAllocConv rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxSetConvClass rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxSetConvClass rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cmrcv rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cmrcv rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciSpxAllocConv rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciSpxAcceptConv rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciSslSecureInitEnv rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciSslSecureLDAPCRLServer rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciUdpGetNameandAddress rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} FileTransferApp.addMenuFile rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} FileTransferApp.addMenuFile rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciSpxAllocMem rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cmaccp rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cmaccp rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciSpxAllocMem rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxListenConv rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxListenConv rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxAllocConv rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxAllocConv rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciUdpReceive rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciUdpReceive rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciSpxCheckComms rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} select rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} select rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciSpxCheckComms rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciSpxLoadDLLs rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} gethostbyaddr rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxTermVicMq rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxTermVicMq rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxTermVicMq rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxTermVicMq rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} gethostbyaddr rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciSpxLoadDLLs rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxTermVicMq rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxTermVicMq rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxAcceptConv rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxAcceptConv rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxTermVicMq rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxTermVicMq rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciUdpGetUniversalAddress rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciUdpGetUniversalAddress rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxTermVicMq rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxTermVicMq rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciUdpGetUniversalAddress rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciUdpGetUniversalAddress rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciSpxFreeMem rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciSpxFreeMem rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxQueryProcAddr rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxTermVicMq rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxTermVicMq rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxInitVicRsp rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxTermVicMq rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxTermVicMq rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxInitVicRsp rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxQueryProcAddr rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciUdpGetNameandAddress rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciSslSecureLDAPCRLServer rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciSslSecureInitEnv rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} CSQXARCV rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} CSQXARCV rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciSslSecureAllocConv rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciSslSecureAllocConv rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} FileTransferApp.getMessageSize rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} FileTransferApp.getMessageSize rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciSpxFreeConv rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciSpxFreeConv rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciUdpCheckConfig rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciLoadTransportExit rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciFindNewPrimary rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciFindNewPrimary rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cmsend rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cmsend rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} FileTransferApp.addMenuFile rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} FileTransferApp.addMenuFile rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciSpxAllocMem rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cmaccp rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cmaccp rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciSpxAllocMem rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxTermVicMsp rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxInitVicMq rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxInitVicMq rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxTermVicMsp rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxTermVicMq rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxTermVicMq rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} select rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} select rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxQueryProcAddr rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxTermVicMq rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxTermVicMq rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxInitVicRsp rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxTermVicMq rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxTermVicMq rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxInitVicMq rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxInitVicMq rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxInitVicRsp rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} ccxQueryProcAddr rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciSpxFreeMem rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciSpxFreeMem rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciLoadTransportExit rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciUdpCheckConfig rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciSpxAcceptConv rc=MQRC_DUPLICATE_RECOV_COORD
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciSpxAllocConv rc=MQRC_DUPLICATE_RECOV_COORD
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciLu62GetLLU rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciSslSecureOpenEnv rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} cciSslSecureOpenEnv rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
---------------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
--------------------------------------------------------------} cciUdpSend rc=Unknown(F001)
-------------------------------------------------------------} FileTransferApp.addMenuFile rc=Unknown(F001)
------------------------------------------------------------} FileTransferApp.addMenuFile rc=Unknown(1)
-----------------------------------------------------------} cciSpxAllocMem rc=Unknown(F001)
----------------------------------------------------------} cmaccp rc=Unknown(F001)
---------------------------------------------------------} cmaccp rc=Unknown(1)
--------------------------------------------------------} cciSpxAllocMem rc=Unknown(1)
-------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
------------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
-----------------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------------} ccxTermVicMsp rc=Unknown(F001)
---------------------------------------------------} ccxInitVicMq rc=Unknown(F001)
--------------------------------------------------} ccxInitVicMq rc=Unknown(1)
-------------------------------------------------} ccxTermVicMsp rc=Unknown(1)
------------------------------------------------} ccxTermVicMq rc=Unknown(F001)
-----------------------------------------------} ccxTermVicMq rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
---------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
--------------------------------------------} ccxListenConv rc=Unknown(F001)
-------------------------------------------} ccxListenConv rc=Unknown(1)
------------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
-----------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------------} ccxAllocConv rc=Unknown(F001)
---------------------------------------} ccxAllocConv rc=Unknown(1)
--------------------------------------} select rc=Unknown(F001)
-------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
------------------------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
-----------------------------------} select rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------------} ccxQueryProcAddr rc=Unknown(F001)
---------------------------------} ccxTermVicMq rc=Unknown(F001)
--------------------------------} ccxTermVicMq rc=Unknown(1)
-------------------------------} ccxInitVicRsp rc=Unknown(F001)
------------------------------} ccxTermVicMq rc=Unknown(F001)
-----------------------------} ccxTermVicMq rc=Unknown(1)
----------------------------} ccxInitVicMq rc=Unknown(F001)
---------------------------} ccxInitVicMq rc=Unknown(1)
--------------------------} ccxInitVicRsp rc=Unknown(1)
-------------------------} ccxQueryProcAddr rc=Unknown(1)
------------------------} gethostbyaddr rc=Unknown(F001)
-----------------------} gethostbyaddr rc=MQRC_OPTION_ENVIRONMENT_ERROR
----------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
---------------------} cciSpxFreeMem rc=Unknown(F001)
--------------------} cciSpxFreeMem rc=Unknown(1)
-------------------} cciUdpSend rc=Unknown(1)
------------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
-----------------} cciLu62GetLLU rc=Unknown(1)
----------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
---------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
--------------} cciSslSecureOpenEnv rc=Unknown(F001)
-------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
------------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
-----------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
----------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(F001)
---------} *** Unknown Function *** rc=Unknown(1)
--------} cciUdpSend rc=Unknown(F001)
-------} FileTransferApp.addMenuFile rc=Unknown(F001)
------} FileTransferApp.addMenuFile rc=Unknown(1)
-----} cciSpxAllocMem rc=Unknown(F001)
----} cmaccp rc=Unknown(F001)
---} cmaccp rc=MQRC_OPTION_ENVIRONMENT_ERROR
--} cciSpxAllocMem rc=Unknown(1)
-} cciUdpSend rc=Unknown(1)
} cciSpxFreeMem rc=Unknown(F001)
{ xcsFFST


Component Dumps (Thread 00000001)
-------< DNET ".NET" >------
OS Version:         Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1
CLR Version:        2.0.50727.5485
Working Set:        116953088 bytes
Shutdown Started:   False
Thread State:       Running
Thread Priority:    Normal
Apartment State:    MTA
Pool Thread:        False
Background Thread:  False
User Domain Name:   KDC
User Name:          ALXMQ001$
Interactive User:   False
xcsInitialize Type: 0x00000407
Command Line:       "D:\OurCompany\OURAPP\STAGING_v1.1\Console\OURAPP.WindowsService.exe"
Current Directory:  D:\OurCompany\OURAPP\STAGING_v1.1\Console
Stack Trace:        
   at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)

   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()

   at IBM.WMQ.MQCommonServices.FmtDumpCallback(xcsFmtHandle& Handle, UInt32 ThreadState, UInt32 Component, UInt32 Function)
-------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

Shashi's comments are correct and most appropriate here - use newer (versions and releases) and especially newest (ie most recent fixpacks) versions of MQ as far as possible, and the newer the better (ie MQ v9 is most ideal). Also, if you are a client installation, any version of the client can talk to any version of the server, so you could update just the client without updating the server.

However as a direct answer to this question, there were a number of places in the MQ product where the maintained indenting levels go badly wrong, with a variety of side effects - You can see this is going on in your FDC above in the way the history is so far to the right.  The very first thing I suggest you do is to go the most recent level of 7.0.1.x which is 7.0.1.14 (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21979626), which should apply directly on your installation (and if by some unusual chance it causes problems, it can also rollback worst case!) - You are currently at 7.0.1.0 which is really ancient.

These indenting issues were fixed at various points through the product lifecycle, and usually as part of other fixes, but it can cause very unusual and unpredictable issues. IC70822, IC68684 are two examples where these issues were specifically targetted, but there are others.

Answer (score 0):

You are using GA level of MQ v7.0.1 which is old level. Also MQ v7 is already out of support. I suggest you to move to a supported version, say MQ v7.5 and apply latest fix pack. MQ v9 is the latest version though.